# Give Arc Effect on Buttons for circular menu in android?

Tags: android, button, menu

Hiii
i have to create circular menu after R & D i got the following output which is display in image 1 but i want to give effect like image 2 i will put it my code here so you can check it

> My current Output image 1 in this button and text display horizontally i want to convert this to arc effect both button and text like below image 2

[image]

> i want to make this  buttons like this image

[image]

```
MainActivity.java
```

> public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity {
>
> ```
>           @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>   }
>
>           @Override       public void createButtons()         {
>                   for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)            {
>           RotativeButton button = new RotativeButton(this);
>
>           if(i==0)
>           {   
>               button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
>               //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
>               button.setText("Insurance Green");
>               button.setPosition(i);
>               button.setLabel("OPTION "+(i+1));
>               button.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
>           }
>           if(i==1)
>           {
>
>               button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
>               //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
>               button.setText("Insurance Red");
>               button.setPosition(i);
>               button.setLabel("OPTION "+(i+1));
>               button.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
>
>           }
>           if(i==2)
>           {   
>               button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
>               //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
>               button.setText("Insurance Yellow");
>               button.setPosition(i);
>               button.setLabel("OPTION "+(i+1));
>               button.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));   
>
>           }
>           Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
>           intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(i+1));
>           button.setIntent(intent);
>           mButtonList.add(button);
>                       }
>               }
>
>    }
> ```
>
> MenuActivity.java

```
public abstract class  MenuActivity extends Activity {

    protected List<RotativeButton> mButtonList = new ArrayList<RotativeButton>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.common_view);
       // RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, mainLayout, true);
        final RotativeMenuView customView = (RotativeMenuView) findViewById(R.id.rotativeMenuView);
        final Button okBtn = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
        customView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                if(okBtn.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    customView.addButtons(mButtonList);
                    customView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

            }

        });
        createButtons();
    }

    protected abstract void createButtons();

}
```

RotativeButton.java

```
public class RotativeButton extends Button {

    private int position;
    private Intent intent;
    private String label;

    public RotativeButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public Intent getIntent() {
        return intent;
    }

    public void setIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }

}
```

> RotativeMenuView.java

```
public class RotativeMenuView extends RelativeLayout
{

    private List<RotativeButton> _buttonList;
    private HashMap<Integer, Point > _pointForPosition = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
    private HashMap<Integer, RectF > _rectForPosition = new HashMap<Integer, RectF>();
    private TextView titleTv;

    public RotativeMenuView(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
    } 

    public RotativeMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    { 
        super(context, attrs); 
    } 

    public RotativeMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    { 
        super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
    } 


    public void addButtons(List<RotativeButton> buttonList) {

        final Button okBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
        titleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTv);

        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RotativeButton activeButton = getActiveButton();
                Intent i = activeButton.getIntent();
                getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        _buttonList = buttonList;
        int numberOfButtons = buttonList.size();
        final double angle = 360 / numberOfButtons;

        int okWidth = okBtn.getMeasuredWidth();
        int okHeight = okBtn.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.e("OK_WIDTH", String.valueOf(okWidth));
        Log.e("OK_HEIGHT", String.valueOf(okHeight));

        int okLeft = okBtn.getLeft();
        int okTop = okBtn.getTop();

        Log.e("okLeft", String.valueOf(okLeft));
        Log.e("okTop", String.valueOf(okTop));

        int distance = okWidth;

        Log.e("distance", String.valueOf(distance));

        final int[] point = new int[2];
        okBtn.getLocationInWindow(point);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {

            RotativeButton rotativeButton = buttonList.get(i);
            int position = rotativeButton.getPosition();
            int buttonHeight = rotativeButton.getBackground()
                    .getIntrinsicHeight();
            int buttonWidth = rotativeButton.getBackground()
                    .getIntrinsicWidth();
            int diffHeight = (okHeight / 2) - (buttonHeight / 2);
            int diffWidth = (okWidth / 2) - (buttonWidth / 2);

            float newAngle = (float) angle * position;

            Point nextPoint = nextPosition(okTop + diffHeight, okLeft
                    + diffWidth, newAngle, distance);
            int newLeft = nextPoint.x;
            int newTop = nextPoint.y;

            final RectF okRect = new RectF(point[0] - newLeft
                    - okBtn.getWidth() + diffWidth, point[1] - newTop
                    - okBtn.getHeight() + diffHeight, (point[0] - newLeft)
                    + okBtn.getWidth() + diffWidth, (point[1] - newTop)
                    + okBtn.getHeight() + diffHeight);

            rotativeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final RotativeButton clickedButton = (RotativeButton) v;

                    int position = clickedButton.getPosition();
                    if (position == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int total = _buttonList.size();
                    final int clickedPosition = total - position;
                    double angle = 360 / total;
                    titleTv.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                        final RotativeButton currentButton = _buttonList.get(i);
                        position = currentButton.getPosition();
                        RectF rectF = _rectForPosition.get(position);
                        float startAngle = (float) angle * position;

                        Path aPath = new Path();
                        aPath.addArc(rectF, startAngle, (float) angle
                                * clickedPosition);

                        Animation anim = new PathAnimation(aPath);
                        anim.setDuration(500);
                        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {                             
                                currentButton.setClickable(false);
                                okBtn.setClickable(false);

                            }

                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                currentButton.setClickable(true);
                                okBtn.setClickable(true);
                                updatePosition(currentButton, clickedPosition);
                                currentButton.clearAnimation();
                            }
                        });
                        anim.setFillBefore(true);
                        currentButton.startAnimation(anim);

                    }
                }
            });

            LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = newTop;
            params.leftMargin = newLeft;
            addView(rotativeButton, params);

            if (position == 0) {
                applyLabel(rotativeButton.getLabel());
            }

            _pointForPosition.put(position, nextPoint);
            _rectForPosition.put(position, okRect);
        }

    }

    public  void updatePosition(final RotativeButton currentButton, int diffPosition){
        int total = _buttonList.size();
        int currentPosition = currentButton.getPosition();
        int newPosition = currentPosition + diffPosition;
        if(newPosition >= total ){
            newPosition -= total;
        }
        currentButton.setPosition(newPosition);

        Point pointForPosition = _pointForPosition.get(newPosition);
        int newLeft = pointForPosition.x;
        int newTop =  pointForPosition.y;

        Log.d("CustomView", "Button: "+ currentButton.getPosition()+ "("+currentButton.getLabel()+") , New Left:" +newLeft+" top: "+ newTop);


        currentButton.layout(newLeft, newTop, 
                newLeft + currentButton.getMeasuredWidth(), newTop + currentButton.getMeasuredHeight());

        Log.d("CustomView", "Moving from:" +currentPosition+" to: "+currentButton.getPosition() + "code: " +currentButton.getLabel());

        if (newPosition == 0) {
            applyLabel(currentButton.getLabel());
        }
    }

    protected void applyLabel( String label) {
        titleTv.setText(label.toUpperCase());
        titleTv.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    private Point nextPosition(int okTop, int okLeft, double angle, int distance) {

        int x = okLeft + (int) (distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
        int y = okTop + (int) (distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
        Log.e("X", String.valueOf(x));
        Log.e("Y", String.valueOf(y));
        Point p = new Point();
        p.set(x, y);
        return p;
    }

    private RotativeButton getActiveButton()
    {
        for (RotativeButton aButton : _buttonList)
        {
            int position = aButton.getPosition();
            if(position == 0)
            {
                return aButton;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> PathAnimation.java

```
public class PathAnimation extends Animation {
    private PathMeasure measure;
    private float[] pos = new float[2];

    public PathAnimation(Path path) {
        measure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t){
        measure.getPosTan(measure.getLength() * interpolatedTime, pos,null);
        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(pos[0], pos[1]);
    }
}
```